# From queryset to list, is it expensive operation?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I want to get item number in queryset.

In pure python we can do this, to find the item number in the list:

```
a = 1
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
numbers.index(a)
>>> 0
```

In django querysets i can`t do this, but i can do this:

```
# a - some instance of `model_name` model.
qs = model_name.objects.all()
model_name_objects = list(qs)
model_name_objects.index(a)
```

From queryset to list, is it expensive operation?

**UPD:**
Usecase:

I have a two models:

```
class Order(models.Model):
     # some fields

class OrderItem(models.Model):
     order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='order_items')
```

I want to know which number has some OrderItem instance in Order.order_items.all() queryset.

**UPD2:**

I want to display this number in OrderItem admin field:

```
class OrderItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = OrderItem
    # some standart fields        
    list_display = ('display_item_number')

    def display_item_number(self, obj):
        b = obj.order.order_items.all().count()
        return '{}/{}'.format(a, b)
```

Where `a` is the OrderItem instance number in Order.order_items.all() queryset.

Comment: Why do you want to find the index? What's the usecase?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary update a question with usecase.

Comment: Your use case doesn't show what you are doing with that number. There is almost certainly a better way of doing it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman i want to use this number in admin field

Comment: @AlekseySergeev In other words, tell us what you _want to achieve_ in the big picture, rather than how to make your solution work better

Comment: @bakkal update question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid evaluating the whole queryset, e.g.

```
for i, item in enumerate(model_name.objects.all()):
    if item == some_item:
         break
else:
    # iterated through the whole queryset without finding the item
    i = None

if i is not None:
    print i
else:
    print "Not found"
```

Django and the underlying db library will fetch pages of query results as you iterate over the queryset.

I am guessing for your use case you are considering something like:

```
order = Order.objects.get(pk=123)
order_items = list(order.order_items.all())
```

You may expect that an individual order will only ever have a small number of order items and your code will have to display them all anyway... in this case it's probably no big deal to just list-ify the whole queryset.